# Netlify deploy failed to compile React SPA

Tags: reactjs, npm, netlify

I'm able to start the app locally but when attempting to deploy the site, I'm getting the following error log
[image]

Between the `Failed to compile.` text and `npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE` there seems to be a couple warnings i.e. use of == instead of === and unused variables.

Build command `npm run build`
Publish directory tried both `build` and `build/`

Is that what's really causing the failure to deploy or is it something else?

Comment: Your eslint warnings will be considered as errors when you are running trying to deploy coz the env `process.env.CI` is set to true. In local env, these warnings wont interfere in your build. The best option would be to fix these warnings or try to disable the `lint` for those specific ones which you want to ignore.

Comment: Read this post for more clarification and how to remove them from the `Netlify` community themselves https://community.netlify.com/t/new-ci-true-build-configuration-treating-warnings-as-errors-because-process-env-ci-true/14434

Comment: @Panther thank you! Looks like they rolled this out last month. I know it's not best practice but if I wanted to shut that off, would I do so in the Settings -> Environment -> edit variables section?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the warnings from your code. That's why the build is failing. You have multiple warnings as shown in this console output. Their CI pipeline is treating warnings as errors because `process.env.CI` is set to true.

Comment: Also, I was able to shut that off by setting `CI` to `false` in the Settings -> Environment -> edit variables section?

Comment: Yes that should work!! Better still would be to remove the warnings altogether.

Comment: I like to live dangerously

Comment: Stackoverflow to the rescue again ! I also like living dangerously  :D